# Use External fonts in fragment

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set the custom fontface of a textview in fragment. I have seen some tuts and traversed some stackoverflow questions also, and tried to set the fontface using custom fonts but its giving error. I have placed my font file in "assets/fonts" folder.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, null);
        String fontPath = "fonts/AGENCYR.ttf";

        // text view label
        TextView txtGhost = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.featured_tourname);

        // Loading Font Face
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), fontPath);

        // Applying font
        txtGhost.setTypeface(tf);
        return root;
    }
```

This is my logcat output:

```
07-06 18:10:47.834: E/Trace(1372): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.travelplanner/com.example.travelplanner.FeaturedTourActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:175)
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:149)
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at com.example.travelplanner.FragmentOne.onCreateView(FragmentOne.java:29)
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:551)
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1164)
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5114)
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
07-06 18:11:11.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     ... 11 more
```

Any help wud be appreciated..

Comment: code looks good. Are you sure the file is not corrupted and is accessible inside assets/fonts ?

Comment: this is fragment and the activity file is FeaturedTourActivity.java..and the file is in project scope according to me as i can navigate to the activity from another activity..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either you do not have `assets/fonts/AGENCYR.ttf` in your project, or that font is not compatible with Android for some reason. If you try a different font, and that one works, then `AGENCYR.ttf` may simply not be usable on Android.

Also, please take licensing into account. If you do not have a distribution license for `AGENCYR.ttf`, you should not be packaging it into your application.